# Question about proof of $|\langle \vec x, \vec y \rangle |\leq |\vec x | |\vec y|$ for an inner product $\langle \rangle$ on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I have a couple questions about the proof of this inequality.

This is listed as Theorem $3.1$ in *Advanced Calculus of Several Variables* (Edwards).

For notational convenience, $x,y,u,v$ are vectors.

If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product on a vector space $V$, then $$|\langle x,y\rangle| \leq |x||y|$$ for all $x,y \in V$ where the norm $|x|:=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$.

**Proof.** The inequality is trivial if either $x$ or $y$ is zero, so assume neither is. If $u=x/|x|$ and $v=y/|y|$, then $|u|=|v|=1$. Hence

\begin{align} 0 \leq (|u-v|)^2 &= \langle u-v, u-v\rangle\\
&= |u|^2 - 2\langle u,v\rangle + |v|^2 \bigstar\\
&= 2-2\langle u,v\rangle. 
\end{align}

So $\langle u,v \rangle \leq 1$, that is $\langle x/|x|, y/|y| \rangle \leq 1$, or $$\langle x,y \rangle \leq |x||y|.$$

Replacing $x$ by $-x$, we obtain $$-\langle x,y \rangle \leq |x||y| \bigstar$$  also, so the inequality follows. $\Box$

**Question.** I understand every step of this proof except the steps I labeled with $\bigstar$. I don't see how the first one follows from $\langle u-v, u-v\rangle$, and I'm not sure why in the last step we are allowed to move the negative sign outside the inner product.

Comment: bilinearity and arbitrariness of x

Comment: @psl2Z Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Real inner product is a bilinear map. Use homogeneity in first slot i.e $\langle \lambda u, v\rangle=\lambda\langle u, v\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's using the fact that:
$$\langle x+y,z \rangle = \langle x,z \rangle + \langle y,z \rangle$$
$$\langle \alpha x, y \rangle = \alpha \langle x,y \rangle$$
when $\alpha$ is a real number. The same equalities hold when you consider the second slot, rather than the first like I've done, due to the symmetry of the inner product. So:
$$\langle u-v,u-v \rangle = \langle u-v,u \rangle + \langle u-v,-v \rangle = \langle u-v,u \rangle - \langle u-v,v \rangle$$
Then, we can split these two terms up:
$$\langle u-v,u-v \rangle = \langle u,u \rangle + \langle -v,u \rangle -\langle u,v \rangle - \langle -v,v \rangle$$
Now, using the second property on $-v = (-1)v$ and using the symmetry of the inner product, we get that:
$$\langle u-v,u-v \rangle = |u|^2 -2 \langle u,v \rangle + |v|^2 $$

Next, for your last step, you have derived that:
$$\langle x,y \rangle \leq |x| \cdot |y|$$
Replacing $x$ with $-x$, you get:
$$\langle -x,y \rangle \leq |-x| \cdot |y| = |x| \cdot |y|$$
Using the second property of the inner product above, we finally obtain:
$$-\langle x,y \rangle \leq |x| \cdot |y|$$